# Options left unprocessed

Tags: python, shell, getopt

I have just run into this problem:

```
couchy.py -H myhost-a version -E no connection --nagios
```

`couchy.py` is a tool of mine using `getopt`.

Please note that there is a mistake in the calling parameters: `no connection` is not quoted (it should be `"no connection"`), so that the `-E` flag sees only `no` as paramter. And even worse, there is a nasty side-effect: the `--nagios` flag is left unprocessed. It seems that the first entry not related to an option flag (in this case `connection`) stops flag processing.

As a result, my tool is not producing a nagios suited exit code, just a normal exit code (in this case `0`), which nagios interprets as `OK: no error`, and I miss the alarm.

Since I make this error (not quoting properly the parameters) quite often, I would like to avoid the side-effect: is there a way to force getopt to process all flags, until the end of the command line?

Comment: Is there some reason to avoid using `argparse`?

Comment: Nothing, except that I will have to rewrite some code. Does `argparse` solve this issue? Any other advantage of `argparse`? Is it state of the art? Is `getopt` deprecated?

Comment: `argparse` works the way you'd like in this case, treating the last `--nagios` as an option.  It's included in python 2.7, and the `argparse` module can be installed on much older python versions if you are stuck with those.

Comment: If not quoting `no connection` is a mistake, aren't there other side effects to worry about, such as `couch.py` not working as intended? I would work on correct quoting before looking for hacks to mitigate that mistake.